# Can I make a Visual Studio solution file to automatically download a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I am learning how to use Visual Studio and publish/consume NuGet packages. After following these tutorials:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/overview-and-workflow

I can create a simple NuGet package and publish/build it fine, as well as find the resulting .csproj project file.

One task I've been assigned is creating a Visual Studios Solution File that will automatically download a NuGet package, but I haven't seen this talked about in the NuGet documentation yet.

How can I to create a Solution File ( or maybe a project file?) for Visual Studio 2019, such that any user can consume (run?) this file with their project, to have NuGet project automatically downloaded to their Visual Studio project?

Comment: Do you mean _automatic NuGet **restore**?_  VS already does that.  Unless you mean _automatic adding of a NuGet package to a project which did not previously reference said package_ then I'm not aware of such a feature.   You could possibly create a VSIX and interact with VS directly.

Comment: If it is a common nuget package in repositories like nuget.org, any one can use your project and when they build it will automatically restore. But if you are creating your own nuget package , you might have to upload in your organization repository and then the user will have to list your org's repository as source in nuget settings. Only then they will be able to automatically restore your custom nuget .

Comment: @MickyD interesting, I know you can search for a NuGet package through the visual studio interface to download. But If I have a package hosted in a private artifactory repo, wondering if there are any other ways in visual studio to download it

Comment: As long as they have access to that private repo set up, the experience for them would be no different than their experience getting packages from the public nuget.org repo.

Answer (score 0):

OP:

> I can create a simple NuGet package and publish/build it fine, as well as find the resulting .csproj project file.

...and OP:

> I know you can search for a NuGet package through the visual studio interface to download. But If I have a package hosted in a private artifactory repo, wondering if there are any other ways in visual studio to download it

So I am assuming you have already published the NuGet package, referenced it in your projects via **Manage NuGet Packages for solution...** at least once and committed the results to source control for others in your team to use.  But the problem is that you would some form of **automatic workflow** so that **when your team members open the solution, the packages are automatically restored** even though they are on your **private NuGet server** wherever that may be, **something your team members environment is not currently configured for**.  This is not a problem.

So there's a two ways this can be done:

1. Specifying additional NuGet package sources in **Package Manager Settings** in Visual Studio
2. Modifying NuGet *behaviour* at *solution, user* or *machine* scope

## 1.0 Choices

### 1.1 Manually configure NuGet via Package Manager settings in Visual Studio

#1, is arguably the *easiest* as is done via VS's user interface.  Unfortunately it does require team members to **manually** apply these settings which is something you wanted to avoid in the first place.   Additionally is is essentially *user-scope* so **will affect any solution you open in Visual Studio** leading to possible problems if multiple solutions are fighting over custom configuration:

[image]

Also be warned, if like me you are working-from-home and have added your employer's NuGet server to the above, don't be surprised that the build suddenly stops working, specifically NuGet restore.  I often find myself having to re-authenticate with my employer account or temporally disabling the custom NuGet source.

[image]

### 1.2 Configure NuGet via NuGet.config files present in source control

In this option you configure NuGet via **nuget.config** files, something that can be added to **source control**.  Why is that important?  Well when your team grabs the latest code say via Git, they'll also find a brand spanking new **nuget.config** in the repo's root folder that Visual Studio (and **CI** servers for that matter) will detect, leading to an **automatic solution-specific configuration of NuGet** that will **add your custom NuGet packages to the restore operation when you go to build your solution**.  Yay!.

[image]

You have complete freedom over where such customisation are applied depending upon scope:

- solution
- user
- machine

MSDN has this to say on **nuget.config** files:

> nuget.config is an XML file containing a top-level  node, which then contains the section elements described in this topic. Each section contains zero or more items. See the examples config file. Setting names are case-insensitive, and values can use environment variables.<sup>1</sup>

...and:

> NuGet's behavior is driven by the accumulated settings in one or more NuGet.Config (XML) files that can exist at project-, user-, and computer-wide levels. A global NuGetDefaults.Config file also specifically configures package sources. Settings apply to all commands issued in the CLI, the Package Manager Console, and the Package Manager UI.<sup>2</sup>

Here's an example **nuget.config**.  Note how I list my custom NuGet package source first (though not entirely necessary) before listing the standard NuGet source.  The config file does not have to exist in the same folder as the Visual Studio solution (**.sln**) file but perhaps in the repo root (see below) so when the solution is built, preference is given to it over any other settings (including what is in VS's user interface):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <clear />
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
    </config>
    <packageSources>
        <!-- When <clear /> is present, previously defined sources are ignored -->
        <!-- Remove this tag or un-comment the nuget.org source below to restore packages from nuget.org -->
        <!-- For more info, see https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file -->
        <clear />       
        <add key="Contoso" value="https://mickyd.com/packages/" />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>

    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>

    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Microsoft recommends that you place the **nuget.config** file (my emphasis):

> ...**in the root of your project repository**. This is considered a best practice as it promotes repeatability and ensures that different users have the same NuGet configuration.<sup>1</sup>

Be sure to check out the rather detailed Example config file on MSDN.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> *["nuget.config reference"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)*, MSDN

2 *["Common NuGet configurations"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior)*, MSDN

3 *["Example config file"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#example-config-file)*

Comment: your nuget.config includes references to the packageSource, but can I include an actual package with a specific version in the nuget.config, which will get downloaded instantly when the project is opened for a new user?

Comment: @POVR2 _"...but can I include an actual package with a specific version in the nuget.config..."_ - no, that's not the purpose of the **nuget.config** file.  However if you list your private repo then open the solution, it will be automatically downloaded when you go to build.